# Real-time Face Recognition

Tags: python, api, machine-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

I want to build a real-time face recognition system with great accuracy.

I tried Face Embedding Models like Facenet but the accuracy wasn't that good(Although I used euclidean distance and not any classification/clustering algorithm) but the distances of two different images of the same face were always more than 2.5(the maximum should be around 1.1 according to the paper). Probably, because the public model of facenet is not well trained.

Then I also tried with AWS rekognition API but it takes around 1 sec to get a response from the server, so I can't use it for real-time face recognition.

Is there any model/API, which is enough accurate and fast for real-time face recognition?

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked this https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/ because this works perfectly well for me.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but the accuracy wasn't that good. It was running on RPI-3 that might be a reason but still it should affect speed and not accuracy (correct me if I am wrong). What were your system specs?

Comment: windows 10 8GB ram intel i7

Comment: if your results deviate from those reported in the paper, work on finding what you do differently from the paper.

Answer (score 0):

deepface is a pretty facial recognition library. It wraps state-of-the-art face recognition models including VGG-Face and Google Facenet. It offers to run real time face recognition with a few lines of code.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
models = ['VGG-Face', 'Facenet', 'OpenFace', 'DeepFace', 'DeepID', 'Dlib']
DeepFace.stream(db_path = "C:/facial_db", model_name = models[1])
```

Herein, VGG-Face got 98.78%; FaceNet got 99.65%; OpenFace got 92.92%; Dlib got 99.38% on Labeled Faces in the Wild (LFW) data set. You just need to pass the model name as input to the stream function.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a deep-learning-based vector embedding and a similarity search engine over these embedding vectors.

Here is a nice demonstration of "deepface" library and a similarity search service:
https://sefiks.com/2021/05/19/large-scale-face-recognition-with-pinecone-vector-database/?r=0